# book like Allan Gut's intermediate probability course, but with solutions

Tags: probability, book-recommendation

I want to self study some probability and I am looking for a book like Allan Gut's intermediate probability course, but with solutions.

Especially I am interested in books that cover multivariate normals and different convergence concepts like Allan does. Also coverage of some Wiener or Poisson processess is good, but not critical. Gut's book covers all of these topics, but unfortunately has no solutions.

Could you please recommend me books that cover these topics and have a good number of exercises with solutions?